# POST requests to api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com from docker in WSL2 with mirrored networking not working when wireguard VPN enabled

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, wireguard

I am trying to access the Microsoft Azure translator API from inside docker in WSL2:

```
curl -v "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=es"   -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxx"   -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"   -d "[{'Text':'Hello friend.'}]"
```

The query works from WSL2 outside of docker with the Windows wireguard VPN active and `networkingMode=mirrored` active, suggesting that "it works" from WSL2 over the VPN to the Azure API. Without the VPN inside the docker container the query also works fine, suggesting it's a network issue but only when the VPN is activated. Certain *other* queries work fine when both inside docker and with the VPN active, e.g, `curl -v https://monip.org` works fine.

The query that fails seems to fail at the TLS handshake stage, so a basic connection is established:

```
* Host api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 20.43.132.97
*   Trying 20.43.132.97:443...
* Connected to api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com (20.43.132.97) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
-> hangs here
```

When it works I get the following directly after the point where it hangs.

```
...
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
...
```

I originally noticed the issue in Python3 code but the same issue appears with `curl`. Both the docker image and wsl2 in these tests are Ubuntu 22.04 but I also saw it in the python 3.12.2-slim docker image.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: A note to potential close-votes (since I see there's one here already).  This feels on-topic to me, as the OP has clearly stated that other URLs work, and that the difficulty is with this particular API endpoint only.  While I'm guessing that the ultimate solution is going to be a non-programming one, the attempted use and failure of this API endpoint is, regardless, on-topic IMHO.